# Convert python dictionary to xml string without using build-in functions

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values(string, list ,dict) i want to convert that dictionary to xml format string.

The values contains might be sub dictionaries and list(not a fixed format). so i want to get all the values from the dict and form the xml string without using any build-in function like(import xml, ElementTree, etc.).

for example:

input :

```
{'Employee':{ 'Id' : 'TA23434', 'Name':'Kesavan' , 'Email':'k7@gmail.com' , 'Roles':[ {'Name':'Admin' ,'RoleId':'xa1234' },{'Name':'Engineer' , 'RoleId':'xa5678' }], 'Test':{'a':'A','b':'b'} }}
```

Output should be:

```
<Employee>
       <Id>TA23434</Id>
       <Name>Kesaven</Name>
       <Email>, ..... </Email>
       <Roles>
             <Roles-1>
                         <Name>Admin</Name>
                         <RoleId>xa1234</RoleId>
             </Roles-1>
             <Roles-2>
                         <Name>Admin</Name>
                         <RoleId>xa1234</RoleId>
             </Roles-2>
       <Roles>
       <Test>
             <a>A</a>
         <b>B</b>
       </Test>  
</Employee>
```

Can anyone advise on this which way is easy for doing this.

Comment: this is a typical homework assignment. please explain what you tried, then we might be able to help

Comment: @tback Please don't use the `homework` tag anymore. It's officially deprecated.

Comment: @Mr.Steak sorry, I didn't know that. Won't use it again.

Comment: What is to be used instead of "homework" ? Can we have a link to where this discussion happened?

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: I guess with *without using any build-in function* you mean without using any other *(XML-parsing) modules*, since otherwise it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
def to_tag(k, v):
    """Create a new tag for the given key k and value v"""
    return '<{key}>{value}<{key}/>'.format(key=k, value=get_content(k, v))

def get_content(k, v):
    """Create the content of a tag by deciding what to do depending on the content of the value"""
    if isinstance(v, str):
        # it's a string, so just return the value
        return v
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
        # it's a dict, so create a new tag for each element
        # and join them with newlines
        return '\n%s\n' % '\n'.join(to_tag(*e) for e in v.items())
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        # it's a list, so create a new key for each element
        # by using the enumerate method and create new tags
        return '\n%s\n' % '\n'.join(to_tag('{key}-{value}'.format(key=k, value=i+1), e) for i, e in enumerate(v))

d = {'Employee':{ 'Id' : 'TA23434', 'Name':'Kesavan' , 'Email':'k7@gmail.com' , 'Roles':[ {'Name':'Admin' ,'RoleId':'xa1234' },{'Name':'Engineer' , 'RoleId':'xa5678' }], 'Test':{'a':'A','b':'b'} }}

for k,v in d.items():
    print to_tag(k, v)
```

I added some comments, but it should be clear what's happening and it should be enough to get you startet.

`dict`s are not ordered in python, so the resulting XML is also not ordered.

**Result:**

```
<Employee>
<Email>k7@gmail.com<Email/>
<Test>
<a>A<a/>
<b>b<b/>
<Test/>
<Id>TA23434<Id/>
<Roles>
<Roles-1>
<RoleId>xa1234<RoleId/>
<Name>Admin<Name/>
<Roles-1/>
<Roles-2>
<RoleId>xa5678<RoleId/>
<Name>Engineer<Name/>
<Roles-2/>
<Roles/>
<Name>Kesavan<Name/>
<Employee/>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Steak. I have found a solution another way(recursive method).